# Excel VBA - User Defined Function - Variable size parameters

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a User Defined Function that calculates true inventory Weeks of Cover. This function will only have two input parameters: total inventory, and weekly forecast data. The weekly forecast data will be arranged in a row that the user can select for input. I want it to work like a SUM function where the user selects the parameter size of the range with their mouse or by manually keying it in during input. I have no idea how to accomplish this. I know what i want to do with the data once i have it in the UDF, but i am struggling on how to actually ingest the data i need. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crude example, but place something like this in a standard code module:

```
Public Function SumMyData(rngToSum As Range) As Double

Dim weeksOfCover As Double

weeksOfCover = 10.54

 SumMyData = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rngToSum) * weeksOfCover

End Function
```

Then in your workbook, use as `=SumMyData(C3:C20)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. What if i wanted to work with each cell in the range individually instead of a sum? Is there a way to load each cell in the range into an array?

Comment: You could just use a `For Each` loop within the UDF code, e.g.

`Dim rCell As Range
: 
For Each rCell In rngToSum
: 
'// Do Something
: 
Next rCell`